# How to replicate the column section option into a button in a grid's topbar?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In Extjs 4 every column has an option for selecting the visible columns, like this:

[image]

How can I replicate the same functionality into the grid's topbar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. Just see the source of `Ext.grid.header.Container #getMenu #getMenuItems`

- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.header.Container
- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Container2.html#Ext-grid-header-Container

Comment: Where can I access the header container inside the grid? I can't find it.

Comment: I mean u can use this code to create your toolbar button's menu. not reuse the menu instance. u can access it by grid.headerCt

Comment: Can I use the object coming from the #getMenuItems inside a tool or a toolbar button?